# find one value in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried multiple ways.
I have below data frame and I have EMP ID from other process. I want to find EMP name based on EMP ID.

```
EMP ID  Name EMP    Location
1      John A       New York
2      Paul         London
3      Adam K       London
4      Lawrence L   London

below code in not working 

emp_name= df['EMP ID']==id_no
print(emp_name[Name Emp])
```

I want Name - Paul for EMP ID =2

Am I passing EMP ID right in data frame?
I tried df.query also. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `df["EMP ID"]==id_no`, you will get a **series** of boolean which represents a result of elementwise comparison:

```
df["EMP ID"] == 2

0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: EMP ID, dtype: bool
```

Assuming `EMP ID` is unique for each `Name EMP`, you can make a new series that can act as a dict:

```
s = df.set_index("EMP ID")["Name EMP"]
s[id_no]
```

Output:

```
"Paul"
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I do not have unique in each case and i want to find value based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['EMP ID']==id_no]['Name EMP']
```

This will return 'Paul' as the output for **id_no**=2

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is good. how can I include another condition like ..EMP_id= '' and Location = ''

Comment: `df.loc[(df['EMP ID']==id_no) & (df['Location']=="London")]['Name EMP']`

Comment: In some cases, I am getting more than one values. How can I pick first value ?